# sql: rr date format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, nsdateformatter, sqldatetime

My question has to do with the 5th command.

1. `create ex_table(on_date date);`
2. `insert into ex_table values(to_date('23-aug-75','dd-mm-rr'));`
3. `insert into ex_table values(to_date('23-aug-75','dd-mm-yy'));`

After the applying the above 3 commands (executed in 2015):

4. `select to_char(on_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') from ex_table;`

Results:

```
on_date
-------
23-aug-1975
23-aug-2075
```

5. `select to_char(on_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') from ex_table where on_date='23-aug-75';`

Results:

```
on_date
-------
23-aug-1975
```

Why is the result of 5th command `23-aug-1975` and not `23-aug-2075` or both?

I am asking this because if command #2 is not executed, then the result would definitely contain `23-aug-2075`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
where on_date='23-aug-75'
```

It's actually translating that to:

```
where on_date=to_date('23-aug-75') -- without the fmt parameter.
```

Because no format is specified explicitly, the string gets parsed and converted to a date according to the current `nls_date_format` session value.  Most likely, your session value is `DD-MON-RR`.  You can check by querying:

```
select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

If that's the case, then the documentation on the [The RR Datetime Format Element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) explains how the year is determined for the string `75` if the current date is `2015`:

> If the specified two-digit year is 50 to 99, then [...] If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the first 2 digits of the returned year ***are 1 less*** than the first 2 digits of the current year.

So, applying the above rule, when you are applying the condition:

```
where on_date='23-aug-75'
```

... then it's looking for the date of August 23rd, 1975.

In your question you also say:

> I am asking this because if command #2 is not executed, then the result would definitely contain `23-aug-2075`.

I have to disagree with that statement.  There is no way that your query will suddenly start matching to August 23rd, 2075, unless you change the `nls_date_format` session value to something else like `DD-MON-YY`.

So that's the explanation. But as for best practice, why not avoid the ambiguities altogether by always being explicit about the date format you are using and always using 4-digit year formats, or by using the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is so clear and easy to use.

Comment: ya my default is rr i thought it would be yy. ok thanks for the answer.

Comment: RR datetime link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

RR stands for Century and YY stands for Year

You can check the date format of your database as suggested by sstan.

I have remembered it like this way.

**Rule 1 :**

If the current year is between 00-49 and you supplied a value between 00-49 then there will be no change in century i.e. 2015 being the current year and you passed a value 30 then 30 will be interpreted as 2030

**Rule 2 :**

If the current year is between 00-49 and you supplied a value between 50-99 then the century is present minus 1 i.e 2015 being the current year and you passed a value 75 then 75 will be interpreted as 1975.

**Rule 3 :**

Assuming the current year to be between 50-99 and you supplied a value between 00-49 then century will be century + 1 i.e. if current year is 2060 and you supplied a value 23 then it will be interpreted as 2161

**Rule 4 :**

Assuming the current year to be between 50-99 and you supplied a value between 50-99 then there will no change in century i.e. if current year is 2060 and you suppplied a value 56 then it will be interpreted as 2056

Comment: i know about rr date format. I think u dint get my question.my question lie in final line

Comment: Since your datebase nls_date_format parameter is in DD-MON-RR format so all the insertion and comparison will happen on that basis. If command 2 is not executes then you won't be getting any result while executing command 5